# How can I make my Objective-C class conform to Swift's `Equatable` protocol?

Tags: objective-c, swift, protocols, language-interoperability

I have an Objective-C class (that happens to be a button, but that is not important), and at another part of my (mixed language) project, I have an array of these buttons and I'd like to get the index of a button using the `find()` method. Like so:

```
func doSomethingWithThisButtonIndex(index:Int)
{
    let buttons = [firstButton, secondButton, thirdButton]
    if index == find(buttons, firstButton)
    {
        // we've selected the first button
    }
}
```

but I'm getting the

> Type 'ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional' does not conform to protocol equatable

Okay, so lets go to Objective-C and have ButtonThing implement `<Equatable>`. But it doesn't recognize that.

So what am I to do?
For now I'm building around it, forcing the array to be an NSArray and using `indexOfObject`. But this is ugly. And frustrating.

Comment: If my answer doesn't satisfy you, then the only other answer is "It's impossible." You can't make an Objective-C class conform to a Swift protocol unless the protocol is annotated as `@objc` or if you do it from the Swift end. `Equatable` is not annotated as such and it can't possibly make sense for it to be so annotated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, in Swift write a custom `==` operator function for your class.

Second, also in Swift, write a class extension that adds the `Equatable` protocol conformance.

Perhaps, for example:

```
func == (lhs: YourClass, rhs: YourClass) -> Bool {
    // whatever logic necessary to determine whether they are equal
    return lhs === rhs
}

extension YourClass: Equatable {}
```

And now your class conforms to `Equatable`, which is Swift specific.  You can not do this on the Objective-C end because you can not write custom operators for Objective-C.

Comment: @Yerk Read the last line of the answer.  You cannot do this for Objective-C.  Swift's `Equatable` protocol requires a custom operator (specifically, `==`), and there is no way to do this with Objective-C.  Perhaps more importantly,  you should be trying to do this for Objective-C anyway.  Objective-C's `==` is equivalent to Swift's `===` for object references.  We shouldn't want to alter that 30-year-old Objective-C behavior...

Comment: Additionally, the `Equatable` protocol is not defined as being an `@objc` protocol, and therefore the protocol cannot be used from Objective-C at all.  `Equatable` is a **purely** Swift protocol.  The way to make an Objective-C class conform to this protocol is by extending the class from within Swift.  Nothing else can make sense.  You're effectively asking "How can I override the default behavior of `==` in Objective-C?"

Comment: @Alix no. Swift's `===` is roughly equivalent to Objective-C's `==`. It's a reference comparison.

Comment: so in objective-C if I want to test the equality between 2 objects how am I suppose to do it?

Comment: @Honey `[obj1 isEqual:obj2];`.  Some classes, such as `NSString`, have other methods as well, such as `[str1 isEqualToString:str2];`.  In this specific case, `isEqualToString:` and `isEqual:` are equivalent.  And all objects inherit `isEqual:` from `NSObject`, but the default implementation is simply the `==` reference comparison.

Comment: Thanks. I think I wrote my question poorly... in Swift you have `struct Home { var rooms : Int var address: String var city : String}` and then to implement equality you have do a `func == (lhs : Home, rhs : Home) {lsh.rooms == rhs.rooms && lhs.address == rhs.address && lhs.city == rhs.city}` How do you implement such in Objective-c?

Comment: Implement the `isEqual:` method.  You can't override operators in Objective-C (note the last sentence of this answer).

Comment: ohhk...so you mean just *like any other method that you write yourself* write one which its name is `isEqual:` which returns a bool. That's simple. So basically in Swift you are mentioning it in a more explicit way and also have the benefit of using a more readable way ie `==`

Answer (score 2):

If your Objective C class is an NSObject, implement isEqual:

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(_Nullable id)other;
```

This worked for me for Array.index(of: myobject) and == comparisons. NSObject is already Equatable so using a Swift extension does not work.