# Swift generics and extensions need to workout

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

Im learning swift currently. While learning I'm stuck with generics. Im solving one simple problem that -> return index of specified element in an array

```
import UIKit

extension Array
{

func indexOfLetter<T:Equatable>(item:T) -> Int
{
    var i = 0
    for (index, value) in enumerate(self)
    {
        if value == item
        {
            return i
        }
        i++
    }

    return -1;
}
}


var arrayOfItems = ["A","B"]
arrayOfItems.indexOfLetter("A")
```

in this code I'm getting error that we

> Can not compare two operands using == operator which are of type T.

Comment: It doesn't describe your problem, but you *could* eliminate `var i` and just `return index` which is currently needlessly unused... and the method would be better returning an `Int?` and passing back `nil` rather than `-1` when unfound.

Comment: It is the same problem as in the referenced question: You cannot write a method on a generic type that is more restrictive on the template. – In Swift 1.2, you would have to define a global function instead. In Swift 2, you can solve it with a protocol extension.

Comment: I found the solution by unwrapping the objects.
import UIKit

extension Array
{
 
    func indexOfLetter<U:Equatable>(item:U) -> Int
    {
        var i = 0
        for (index, value) in enumerate(self)
        {
            if (value as! NSString) == (item as! NSString)
            {
                return i
            }
            i++
        }
        
        return -1;
    }
}


var arrayOfItems:Array = ["A","B"]
arrayOfItems.indexOfLetter("B")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your problem becomes more clear if we use a letter other than `T` for our generic identifier.

Change the method signature to use the letter `U`.  And now we get this error message:

[image]

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'U'

This is the same error, but it's made more clear by using a different letter.  The `Array` type is already a generic whose generic identifier is `T` for its type.

When we use `U` it unmasks the real problem.

The `Equatable` protocol only requires that our type defines `==` for comparisons to itself.  We could compare two `U`'s as long as `U`'s type is `Equatable`.  But the `Equatable` protocol does not ensure that we can compare a `U` to a `T` using `==`.

[This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31039541/2792531) can provide some insight on the difficulties of using the `Equatable` protocol with generics.